# Using an external class as an Angular provider

Tags: angular

I've build a typescript library which I bundled with Rollup.js and deployed as npm module.  I want to use one of these classes as a singleton so I thought of using Provider.useClass such as:

```
import {FeatureToggleService} from 'cxone-client-services-platform';
...
providers:[
{ provide: FeatureToggleService, useClass: FeatureToggleService}
]
```

Here is the package.json file for npm module.

[image]

and here is the index.d.ts file:

[image]

However the provider statement is causing a big mess with AOT.

I get the following error for a production build (Angular 8) with AOT.

ERROR in ./src/ng2/app/app.module.ngfactory.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'cxone-client-services-platform/lib/feature-toggle-utils/feature-toggle.service' in '/Users/scott/code/cxone/hybrid-webapp-pm/src/ng2/app'

When I turned on verbose logging I see something like this:

```
ERROR in ./src/ng2/app/app.module.ngfactory.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'cxone-client-services-platform/lib/feature-toggle-utils/feature-toggle.service' in '/Users/scott/code/cxone/hybrid-webapp-pm/src/ng2/app'
resolve 'cxone-client-services-platform/lib/feature-toggle-utils/feature-toggle.service' in '/Users/scott/code/cxone/hybrid-webapp-pm/src/ng2/app'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: /Users/scott/code/cxone/hybrid-webapp-pm/package.json (relative path: ./src/ng2/app)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    resolve as module
      looking for modules in /Users/scott/code/cxone/hybrid-webapp-pm/
        using description file: /Users/scott/code/cxone/hybrid-webapp-pm/package.json (relative path: .)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          using description file: /Users/scott/code/cxone/hybrid-webapp-pm/package.json (relative path: ./cxone-client-services-platform/lib/feature-toggle-utils/feature-toggle.service)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/scott/code/cxone/hybrid-webapp-pm/cxone-client-services-platform/lib/feature-toggle-utils/feature-toggle.service doesn't exist
            .ts
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/scott/code/cxone/hybrid-webapp-pm/cxone-client-services-platform/lib/feature-toggle-utils/feature-toggle.service.ts doesn't exist
            .tsx
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/scott/code/cxone/hybrid-webapp-pm/cxone-client-services-platform/lib/feature-toggle-utils/feature-toggle.service.tsx doesn't exist
            .mjs
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/scott/code/cxone/hybrid-webapp-pm/cxone-client-services-platform/lib/feature-toggle-utils/feature-toggle.service.mjs doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/scott/code/cxone/hybrid-webapp-pm/cxone-client-services-platform/lib/feature-toggle-utils/feature-toggle.service.js doesn't exist
            as directory
              /Users/scott/code/cxone/hybrid-webapp-pm/cxone-client-services-platform/lib/feature-toggle-utils/feature-toggle.service doesn't exist
      /Users/scott/code/cxone/hybrid-webapp-pm/src/ng2/app/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /Users/scott/code/cxone/hybrid-webapp-pm/src/ng2/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /Users/scott/code/cxone/hybrid-webapp-pm/src/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /Users/scott/code/cxone/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /Users/scott/code/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /Users/scott/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /Users/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      looking for modules in /Users/scott/code/cxone/hybrid-webapp-pm/node_modules
        using description file: /Users/scott/code/cxone/hybrid-webapp-pm/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          using description file: /Users/scott/code/cxone/hybrid-webapp-pm/node_modules/cxone-client-services-platform/package.json (relative path: ./lib/feature-toggle-utils/feature-toggle.service)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              resolved symlink to /Users/scott/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.0/lib/node_modules/cxone-client-services-platform/lib/feature-toggle-utils/feature-toggle.service
                using description file: /Users/scott/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.0/lib/node_modules/cxone-client-services-platform/package.json (relative path: ./lib/feature-toggle-utils/feature-toggle.service)
                  no extension
                    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                    resolved symlink to /Users/scott/code/cxone-client-platform-services/dist/lib/feature-toggle-utils/feature-toggle.service
                      using description file: /Users/scott/code/cxone-client-platform-services/dist/package.json (relative path: ./lib/feature-toggle-utils/feature-toggle.service)
                        no extension
                          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                          /Users/scott/code/cxone-client-platform-services/dist/lib/feature-toggle-utils/feature-toggle.service doesn't exist
                        .ts
                          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                          /Users/scott/code/cxone-client-platform-services/dist/lib/feature-toggle-utils/feature-toggle.service.ts doesn't exist
                        .tsx
                          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                          /Users/scott/code/cxone-client-platform-services/dist/lib/feature-toggle-utils/feature-toggle.service.tsx doesn't exist
                        .mjs
                          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                          /Users/scott/code/cxone-client-platform-services/dist/lib/feature-toggle-utils/feature-toggle.service.mjs doesn't exist
                        .js
                          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                          /Users/scott/code/cxone-client-platform-services/dist/lib/feature-toggle-utils/feature-toggle.service.js doesn't exist
                        as directory
                          /Users/scott/code/cxone-client-platform-services/dist/lib/feature-toggle-utils/feature-toggle.service doesn't exist
                    /Users/scott/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.0/lib/node_modules/cxone-client-services-platform/lib/feature-toggle-utils/feature-toggle.service doesn't exist
                  .ts
```

There's alot more log however it seems to be much like what I posted.   It almost seems like its not looking in node_modules for the package.

If I create a simple class in the Angular app itself such as
export class ScottService {}

I can do

```
providers:[
{ provide: ScottService, useClass: ScottService}
]
```

This doesn't work when the class is coming in from an outside node module which has been compiled to Javascript.   Is there anyway to make it work?